# A strange jquery issue on wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I can't upload files in my wordpress dashboard uploading page, it noticed that "JQuery is not defined", it seems that all pages which include jquery doesn't work, not only uploading page, just in chrome and firefox, however, my friend logged in in to my dashboard,all that's normal. I'm not sure that it's caused by my theme or browser. I try to reinstall chrome and WordPress,  It doesn't even matter.

Comment: Did you clear browser's cache?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your Wordpress to a new version ? I got the same issue after an upgrade to 3.5 version.

There was a conflit between the version of JQuery in my theme and the one in Wordpress. Try to upgrade Jquery. It works for me :)